# How can I get validation group in javascript event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, validation

I have a button with a validation group.

The button click event calls a jquery function so i get the event to work with. (not using onclientclick)

How do I get the validation group associated with the button using the event?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your defintion of "validation group"? what is html structure to look for it in relation to button? Not nearly enough info given. Providing HTML would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below if you want to validate the form  before java script executes.

```
function myFunction()
{
  if (Page_ClientValidation(validationgroupname))
    {
   /*do my work here*/
    }
 }
```